# data factory - data flow delete row in parquet - sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the upsert if working for the .parquet files by selecting the upsert if setting to true()For example when the source is update ,then the parquet sink is updated accordingly.But if a row is deleted in source it is still shown in sink parquet even when check the Allow Delete.Any suggestions?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just like `Upsert if` is set to `true()`, you have to set `Delete if` to `true()`.

I have tried similar use case and I successfully deleted row in Sink which was also deleted in Source.

**Step1:** I have used CSV file as Source with 10 records.
[image]

**Step2:** Created data flow with AlterRow activity.

Added 2 conditions

```
Upsert if true()

Delete if true()
```

[image]

**Step3:** Here I have stored data in parquet file. All 10 records inserted.

[image]

**Step4:** Now I have deleted first row from my source file.

[image]

**Step5:** Now there are only 9 records in Sink as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this, however I would like to find out how to have a Deleted flag instead of physically removing the row.
For example, if row is deleted from source, the the Deleted column in sink has it set to 1
And note that I am using sink Delta parquet file
Thank you